# Inserting date into my sql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I tried inserting a date into a mysql database. but for some reasons it was processing the information before putting it into the database here is my code

```
define("FRIENDS",  "friends");

if (!$update) { 
     $date = date("m-d-Y");
        $q = "INSERT INTO " . FRIENDS . " VALUES ('$friend2', $date, $status)"; 
    }
```

this is what i see in my database: -2025 instead of 15-05-2015.
i seems like its being subtracted.

And when i use

```
$date = date("m/d/Y");
```

it divides out, leaving `0.000165425971712158` in my database.

Comment: its a table with 3 rows

Comment: must be $friends right? or that should be insert into friends

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote your values.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO " . FRIENDS . " VALUES ('$friend2', $date, $status)";
```

ends up looking like

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_friends VALUES ('friend', 15-05-2015, status)"
```

mysql does the small equation it finds in your sql query; 15 minus 5, minus 2015

quote your values and it becomes a string instead of an expression.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO " . FRIENDS . " VALUES ('$friend2', '$date', '$status')";
```

Comment: *"15 minus 5, minus 2015"* - Yep, sold me on that one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your date format is wrong for MySQL storage.  Create your date using:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

<s>There is also probably an error in your SQL, unless you have a PHP constant set for "FRIENDS".</s>

EDIT: nevermind, you updated your question showing you have the constant set